# Car won't start if the battery has been on for ~5 minutes

Tags: battery, starting, accord, battery-drain

I have a 2006 Honda Accord, and my car battery is not too old (1-2 years). The car starts fine, I don't normally have issues with it. However if I turn off my engine and sit in my car with the battery on for not even five minutes, my car won't start (won't turn over). If I then let it rest for another 10 minutes, it starts fine again.

Even though my car doesn't start, the headlights, interior lights, radio, etc., all work fine. I live in cold climate, but it's not *that* cold here yet (30s and 40s F).

Could I need a new battery replacement, even though my battery is not very old? Or could this be indicative of something else?

Comment: If you let it sit 10 minutes longer and it starts the battery is fine, something else is wrong. It's very hard to say without more information, like OBD codes.

Comment: Can you describe what happens when you try to start the car.? Saying that it won’t start is a bit too vague.  What do you see and hear?

Comment: Had an issue like this once and it was a cracked link inside the battery. Test by fitting a known good battery for a few days. If it cures it then you know.

Comment: A battery load test may be in order here.  Most auto parts stores (depending on where in the world you are of course) off such testing free of charge.

Comment: Agree with @GdB and HandyHowie. I tend to believe the battery is fine, but having more information is necessary. Does it clic, when you try to start? Doe the engine try to turn over, but fails to start? When you say sitting there with battery on, are you in accessory mode or run mode?

Comment: When I try to start the car, it tries to turn over but fails, similar to what I've experienced with a low (but not dead) battery. It dies when I turn my keys one click - the engine is off, but the battery stays on.